# Android AlarmManager.cancel() not actually cancelling alarm/PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Trying to cancel an AlarmManager alarm, isn't quite working.

I create a PendingIntent like so:

```
static PendingIntent makePendingIntent(int id, Bundle bundle)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), mfLocalNotificationManager.class);
    if(bundle != null)
    {
        intent.putExtra(BUNDLE_ID, bundle);
    }

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

}
```

Called from SendLocalNotification:

```
public static int SendLocalNotification(String title, String text, String tickerText, 
        int timeSent, int timeOffset, String sound)
{

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = 
        (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);   

    Bundle notificationData = new Bundle();
    notificationData.putString("title", title);
    notificationData.putString("text", text);
    notificationData.putString("tickerText", tickerText);
    /*snip, bundle stuff*/

    int noteID = title.hashCode();        

    notificationData.putInt("noteID", noteID);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = makePendingIntent(noteID, notificationData);

    if( pendingIntent == null )
    {
            //This should probably be flagged as an error or an assertion. 
        Log.d("[MF_LOG]", "Java intent is null");
            return -1;
    }

    //This isn't my timing code, don't hate me for it
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeOffset);

    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),
                 pendingIntent);

return noteID;
}
```

And attempt to cancel it like so (passing the id we previously got back from SendLocalNotification):

```
public static void CancelNotification(int id)
{
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = 
            (AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = makePendingIntent(id, null);

    //This doesn't work...
    pendingIntent.cancel(); //<- added based on SO post, doesn't help
    alarmMgr.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Nothing seems to work, and I've followed as much of the advice on other posts as I can find (making sure the ID is the same, ensuring the PendingIntent is recreated exactly the same) and it still seems to crash. As a side note, trying to check if a notification exists using the flag PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE also doesn't work, creating a new object instead of returning null.

The device I'm testing this on is a Nexus 7 and I'm building against API 9.

Comment: Never mind, it seems that setting the flag to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT fixed the issue.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer, accept it and delete the comment. Also try not to gave scroll bars in your code :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to recreate your intent and CANCEL it like this:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent peding = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, code, intent,     
                                                 PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
alarm.cancel(peding);
```