# Why my alarm is not being canceled

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i have a service(AlarmService.java) where the alarm is being declared:

```
           Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);             
           intentAlarm.putExtra("Notif_body", Notif_Body);             
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intentAlarm, 0);
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+5*1000, displayIntent);
```

and an activity(user_settings.java) from where I want to delete that alarm once a checkbox is unchecked:

```
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this,TimeAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intentAlarm, 0);               
            alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
```

but it's not working my alarm is not being deleted why is that although the pendingintent is the same as it should be!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was :

instead of adding:

```
if(bool_activate_reminder==true){
//call the alarm method;
}
```

I was doing:

```
 if(bool_activate_reminder=true){//with one equal 
    //call the alarm method;
    }
```

so it was always being accessed... when I fixed it and used the following code in the service:

```
 Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplication(), TimeAlarm.class);    
               //add the notification body to the intent:
               intentAlarm.putExtra("Notif_body", Notif_Body);             
               // create the object
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
               //set the alarm for particular time
                PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
               alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+20*1000, displayIntent);
```

and in the activity:

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplication(),TimeAlarm.class);
            PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);               
            alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
```

it worked just fine..

Answer (score 0):

```
intentAlarm.putExtra("Notif_body", Notif_Body);
```

Put the above line while creating the intentAlarm during cancelling the alarm or remove it from the time when you are setting the alarm. I guess this would work.

Comment: If that doesnt work, you can try
    PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplication(),1,intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343708/android-alarmmanager-cancel-not-actually-cancelling-alarm-pendingintent

Comment: That didn't work either and I also tried that earlier and tried it once again now...

Comment: Could you also try this?  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 

Rather than using the getApplication() object, try with context object (getApplicationContext())

Comment: I also tried that, plus I logged the value of getApplication and it's the same in both cases so that's not the problem but still can't figure out where the problem is!!!!

Comment: now this is equally interesting and frustrating :P as I am doing the same thing in my app and it is working just fine  
How about we try AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);